# Turning the Solution for a Recurrence into a Solution for a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

I was looking into different ways to define the exponential function. I found that one way to do this was to define it as the unique function satisfying the conditions
\begin{align*}
f'&=f\\
f(0)&=1
\end{align*}
I realize we can find an explicit solution by defining $f$ to be the inverse function of 
$$\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$$
but instead of doing this, what if we create a recurrence? For any $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, partition the interval $[0,x]$ using $n+1$ points, $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=x$ where $t_k=kx/n$. We can now create a recurrence which resembles the above differential equation: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{f\left(t_{k+1}\right)-f\left(t_k\right)}{t_{k+1}-t_k}&=f\left(t_k\right)\\
f\left(t_0\right)=1
\end{align*}
Solving, we find 
$$f\left(t_k\right)=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^k$$
giving us 
$$f\left(t_n\right)=f(x)=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
Doing the analogous thing for $x\in \mathbb{R}^{-}$ gives us
$$f(x)=\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{-n}$$
If we take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity, we obtain a solution to the original differential equation. We can do something similar, defining the sine function as the unique function satisfying the conditions
\begin{align*}
f''+f &=0\\
f(0)&=0\\
f'(0)&=1
\end{align*}
Doing the same thing with recurrences, we get something like 
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\left(1+\frac{ix}{n}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac{ix}{n}\right)^n\right]$$
(For this I actually created two recurrence relations, one for $f$ and one for $f'$.) Again, taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity, we get a solution to the original differential equation. My question is, why does this actually work? How can we rigorously justify this?

Comment: You are using a finite difference scheme to approximate the ODE. Look up consistency, convergence, stability & the Dahlquist equivalence theorem. Similar schemes (and more) are used for PDEs as well.

Comment: A 'fast track' result from your observation is that the solution to ODE must be unique (omitting details) if it exists - you get an immediate functional expression $f_n$ that should 'work out/converge' in the limit. (+1)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method